# VPN in Windows SBS 2011 Essentials

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2011

Does SBS 2011 Essentials not support the requires role for setting up VPN natively in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some poking around, and could find little on that since the help files are very new and sparse at this point. I do think that it is entirely possible that they limited or did away with the installation of RRAS, and that the only remote access they support on that edition is the Remote Web Workplace.

If you cannot find it under "Network Policy and Access Services", hit next, then under Roles Services, "Routing and Remote Access Services", the answer is probably no since I doubt they went out of their way to move it.

Post back what you find please.

Comment: I found the RRAS role when I right clicked on Network Policy and Access Services and clicked Add Role Services from there. I have yet to set up the VPN, however, I will post back once I know for sure that VPN specifically does work with 2011 Essentials.

Comment: It works, just make sure you go to the "Add Role Services" area like he mentioned above instead of "Add Roles" which is where I was trying to enable it from.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very complete guide to configuration here:

http://blog.lan-tech.ca/2012/01/28/sbs-2011-essentials-configuring-vpn-access/

It seems to cover everything, including some best practice guidelines.